# zypper search output what does i+ mean?

Tags: opensuse, zypper

I'm struggling to understand what does the '+' symbol mean in the zypper output search.

I have some packages that in the S field have I, others I+.

What is this + ?

For some reason my system hasn't the + in a packet X and I have problems with another packet Y. In another system where there is the + symbol this problem isn't present.

Cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The zypper man page answers your question:

> ```
>        i+      installed by user request
>        i       installed automatically (by the resolver, see section Automatically installed packages)
> ```

Comment: Cheers. So if I've correctly understood it  if there's a plus it means I've typed zypper install packet right?

Comment: Yes, I haven't verified that on every package, but I believe the man page. ;-)